# how to check if an array is null

Tags: php, arrays, curl, foreach

i am parsing a xml api using curl. the curl provides an array and i fetch it using foreach loop but most of the time i get array like below which is not fetched by foreach loop. the array is like below

```
  array(
     [0]=>
      )
```

so how to check if the array is null so that the foreach has not to fetch the null array. i mean which (if()) condition should i use.

the another problem is that why curl gives empty array most of the time. what is the problem. i am working on localhost and the api is called from remote server. please help me.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/empty

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+if+array+is+empty+php

Comment: apart from the [you being supposed to do research before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) questions, how are we supposed to know why some random webservice returns something? It's like asking why didnt Joe come around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

empty()

ie

$test = "";

if (empty($test))
{
echo "true"
}

would return true

Answer (score 1):

See [`is_null();`](http://php.net/is_null) and [`empty();`](http://php.net/empty)

Answer (score 1):

An array cannot be null. A variable can be null if no value is assigned to it, but when you create an empty array and assign it to a variable, the value of that variable is an array - not null.

The array, on the other hand can be empty or have the size of zero. So using empty() or count() would give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an array is null, use the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.
It returns false if array is empty.